# SPO-PowerShell: Get all groups an external user is member of

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I need some help regarding PowerShell and SPO.

I want to have a report showing all groups an external user is a member of in a site collection. For internal users, this is simply done that way:

```
Get-SPOUser -Site *SiteCollection* -LoginName *UserName* | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Groups
```

But i cannot figure out how to get a similar result for external users.

Get-SPOUser is not working with external accounts as far as I can see, Get-SPOExternalUser is not capable of showing the Groups a user is in...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint Online, the user `LoginName` for the external user is formatted as  "`user_contoso.com#ext#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com`".

For example: an external user with "`user@outlook.com`" email, his `LoginName` is "`user_outlook.com#ext#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com`.

Use the following commands to get groups:

```
Get-SPOUser -Site "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/Sites/<site>" -LoginName "user_domain.com#ext#@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Groups
```

Comment: Perfect, this solves my issue! Did not expect to need that extended format...